# Define classes based on variables in PHP

Tags: php, class

So, I'm developing a webapp under my own mvc structure and all Controller classes are defined inside their own files, e.g.: HomeController is defined inside HomeController.php. So my question is: is it possible to automatically define a class based on its file name? Like, I tried to catch the filename using **FILE**, then to define a class based on that.

```
$path = __FILE__; // "C:.../app/Controller/HomeController.php"

$array = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
array_pop($array); // In order to remove "HomeController.php"
$class = end($array); // Controller

$className = 'Home'.$class;
class $className {} // This is not working, so is it possible or not?
```

Comment: Why do you need this? It's just extra lines of code in each file!

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Actually, I'm gonna use it like a function, because this app requires many Controllers, Models, Views and if i need to change one file's name, i should also change the class name inside, so that way it would be more practical, i think hehe

Comment: The problem is to know if is it possible to define a class like 'class $className {}'

Comment: @rolivares93 not very practial. If you change your class name, your entire app might break.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, actually my app is based on the classname which must be the same of the filename

Comment: *"if i need to change one file's name, i should also change the class name inside, so that way it would be more practical"* -- you won't change the class and file names very often. It will probably happen, from time to time, but when it happens, the most probable cause is a refactoring of that class. And that usually involves more changes than just a rename. I cannot tell for others but I rename a class when I realize it does too many things and some of them should go into a new class. Hence, the rename is just a small piece from a larger change.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: you cannot do it the way you want to. What you could do is create code that creates the PHP file and generates a boilerplate class from a template.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much! I'll try to create those boilerplates

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using the infamous PHP function [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
$className = 'Home'.$class;
eval("class $className {}");
```

But it is not practical for your purpose.

This method is used by the testing tools to create mock objects. [PHPUnit's Mock Object library](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects), for example, [uses it](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/c4dd0c9e7fcbf53c6aa48012902be692318c7566/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L305) a lot.